# How do I restore a NuGet package using the CLI?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to restore NuGet packages in my project using the CLI.  The command I  am using looks like this:
NuGet.exe restore [Solution file] -ConfigFile [Config file] -NoCache

[Solution file] is the path to my .sln file

[Config file] is the path to the NuGet.Config file in the .nuget folder of my solution

When I run this command I always get "Unable to find version <Version #> of package ."  This happens for any updated package.

On the same machine, I can then open the solution in Visual Studio and it updates the packages fine.  Visual Studio is set to use the source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json which is the same feed reported as being used from the CLI.  Can't figure out why it works from VS but not the CLI.

Update:
My original nuget.config looked like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
      </solution>
      <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
      </packageSources>
    </configuration>
```

I modified it to this based on the answer from Perry.  I got the same result with the updated config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <config>
    
        </config>
        <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        </packageSources>
        <packageRestore>
           <add key="enabled" value="True" />
           <add key="automatic" value="True" />
        </packageRestore>
        <bindingRedirects>
           <add key="skip" value="False" />
        </bindingRedirects>
        <packageManagement>
           <add key="format" value="0" />
          <add key="disabled" value="True" />
        </packageManagement>
    </configuration>
```

Updated NuGet.exe to version 5.8.0 and set the Verbosity to Detailed and got this result:

```
NuGet Version: 5.8.0.6930
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Users\buildadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\0bsxh5zl.jlh.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Users\buildadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\wc050pok.qyy.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.29\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\5.8.0\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\\" /p:RestoreConfigFile="E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\.nuget\NuGet.Config" /p:SolutionDir="E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\\" /p:SolutionName="DsdMobile"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0113: Google Play requires that new applications must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\Ross.Core.Dex\Ross.Core.Dex.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0114: Google Play requires that application updates must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\Ross.Core.Dex\Ross.Core.Dex.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0113: Google Play requires that new applications must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\Ross.Localization\Ross.Localization.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0114: Google Play requires that application updates must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\Ross.Localization\Ross.Localization.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0113: Google Play requires that new applications must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\Ross.UI\Ross.UI.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0114: Google Play requires that application updates must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\Ross.UI\Ross.UI.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0113: Google Play requires that new applications must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\RossServices\RossServices.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): warning XA0114: Google Play requires that application updates must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.0 (API level 26) or above. You are currently targeting v5.0 (API level 21). [E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\RossServices\RossServices.csproj]

Restoring NuGet package Plugin.Fingerprint.1.4.9.
Missing C:\Users\buildadmin\.nuget\packages\plugin.fingerprint\1.4.9\plugin.fingerprint.1.4.9.nupkg
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.4.9' of package 'Plugin.Fingerprint'.
  C:\Users\buildadmin\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Plugin.Fingerprint.1.4.9' is not found on source 'C:\Users\buildadmin\.nuget\packages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

WARNING: Unable to find version '1.4.9' of package 'Plugin.Fingerprint'.
  C:\Users\buildadmin\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Plugin.Fingerprint.1.4.9' is not found on source 'C:\Users\buildadmin\.nuget\packages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

NuGet Config files used:
    E:\TFSBuilds\Agents\AFSDSDHandheld_Agent\_work\40\s\HANDHELD\Android\2.0\2.0.9\.nuget\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    C:\Users\buildadmin\.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

I am using VS 2019 so I'm not sure if I need to specify that.  I'm assuming the issue has to do with the "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" message, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: How did you write your `nuget.config` file? Could you please share it with us? And the problem is  related to that file.

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT Updated my post to include contents of nuget.config file

Comment: I think your `nuget.exe` is too old. And when I use `nuget.exe` `v2.8.6`,`v 3.3.0`, the error happens. Actually, I test your `nuget.config` with the latest `v5.8.0`,there is no errors. So I think there is no issue with your `nuget.config` file. The issue might be your the version of your `nuget.exe`.

Comment: So I think you should update your nuget.exe to the latest version. So please download  from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) to use the latest nuget.exe `v5.8.0`.

Comment: I also have updated the answer.

Comment: Updated to 5.8.0.  Updated my post to include the results

Comment: Also tried using -MSBuildPath option to specify VS2019 build.  Same error

Comment: Thanks for sharing the detailed log which makes the issue more clear. Please check my `update 2` under the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should check your `nuget.config` file carefully.

This is the right one for nuget.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    
    <config>

    </config>
    <packageSources>
            <add key="public feed" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
    </packageSources>
    <packageRestore>
       <add key="enabled" value="True" />
       <add key="automatic" value="True" />
   </packageRestore>
   <bindingRedirects>
       <add key="skip" value="False" />
   </bindingRedirects>
   <packageManagement>
       <add key="format" value="0" />
      <add key="disabled" value="True" />
  </packageManagement>

</configuration>
```

**Then**, use command `nuget restore xxx\ConsoleApp38.sln -ConfigFile "xxx\ConsoleApp38\.nuget\nuget.config"  -NoCache`, and it can work well.

**At the beginning**, I write any other nodes under `<config></config>` which causes the same error as you said like this:

The wrong one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>

        <packageSources>
            <add key="public feed" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
        </packageSources>

    </config>
</configuration>
```

**After that**, I found that `<config></config>` has the same level as `<packageSources></packageSources>`.

You should follow [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) to write your `nuget.config` file.

**Besides**, if you did not figure your nuget.config file, you could share it with us to let us find the issue. Also, you can use `*` to replace privacy information.

**Update 1**

**Also**,  since your nuget.exe is too old and might have some issues for the old one. You should use the latest `nuget.exe v5.8.0` which I have tested it successfully. So please download from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

**Update 2**

With the further survey, the issue is more clear.

> An error occurred while sending the request. The request was aborted:
> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Your Internet or network protocol might have some problems. If you use any proxy, please disable it. Make sure your Internet is pure.

Further, if this do not help, please follow the suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** open powershell as Administrator, run these:

```
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.3 has been disabled.'

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
```

**2)** use this to turn `TSL 1.2` on.

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:64
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
```

**3)** also, you can try to use `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/` as `nuget.org` source.

Comment: I didn't have TLS 1.3 installed so I skipped #1 and just did #2 and that fixed it!  Thanks so much for the help.